# add a sub domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, subdomain

i have an account with dyndns.com that i use to host my own website from an ubuntu desktop in my home:

```
mydomain.dyndns.org
```

i've added a subdomain as a virtual host in the apache server:

```
mysub.mydomain.dyndns.org
```

i can access it *if* i put an entry in my /etc/hosts file, but i want to be able to access it from anywhere.  is there a (free) way to do this through dyndns.com, or do i need to set up a dns server?  if so where can i get instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, you'd need to have DNS authority over the whole zone/subdomain, which you don't, or have a redirection of type

```
* IN A 1.2.3.4
```

or

```
* IN CNAME somedomain.com
```

If you want to manage subdomains, the best thing to do is to buy yourself a domain. Gandi.net has a good DNS management system, and you can buy domains there.